# Add hour and minute to a django DateTimeField already saved

Tags: python, django

Here is my model  :

```
futureEventDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And now i'am setting futureEventDate  :

```
eventSub.futureEventDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    formEvent["futureEventDate"], "%m/%d/%Y"
).date()
```

But now that it's done i would like to specify hour and minute to eventSub.futureEventDate.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace(..)` for a `datetime` object to specify `hours` and `minutes`, for example:

```
eventSub.futureEventDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    formEvent["futureEventDate"], "%m/%d/%Y"
).replace(hour=14, minute=25)
```

This will thus retain the `date`, but change the time to 14:25. In case the original `datetime` object contains non-zero seconds, and/or microseconds, you can set these to `0` as well:

```
eventSub.futureEventDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    formEvent["futureEventDate"], "%m/%d/%Y"
).replace(hour=14, minute=25, second=0, microsecond=0)
```